# Java nested generic type

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard, unbounded-wildcard

How come one must use the generic type `Map<?, ? extends List<?>>` instead of a simpler `Map<?, List<?>>` for the following `test()` method?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, List<String>> mappy =
        new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

    test(mappy);
}

public static void test(Map<?, ? extends List<?>> m) {}

// Doesn't compile
// public static void test(Map<?, List<?>> m) {}
```

Noting that the following works, and that the three methods have the same erased type anyways.

```
public static <E> void test(Map<?, List<E>> m) {}
```

Comment: What is exactly the compilation error message you get?

Comment: The method `test(Map<?,List<?>>)` in the type `Main` is not applicable for the arguments `(Map<Integer,List<String>>)`

Comment: Not exactly an answer - but you can use `Map<?, List<?>>`. You would then need to use the method with `Map<Integer, List<?>> mappy = new HashMap<>();` as an argument.

Comment: Indeed I can, but then I lose type checking on what I put in my mappy! I could for example write `mappy.put(123, new ArrayList<Integer>())` without error, which is not wanted.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Fundamentally, `List<List<?>>` and `List<? extends List<?>>` have distinct type arguments.

It's actually the case that one is a subtype of the other, but first let's learn more about what they mean individually.

#### Understanding semantic differences

Generally speaking, the wildcard `?` represents some "missing information". It means *"there was a type argument here once, but we don't know what it is anymore"*. And because we don't know what it is, restrictions are imposed on how we can use anything that refers to that particular type argument.

For the moment, let's simplify the example by using `List` instead of `Map`.

- A `List<List<?>>` holds *any kind of List with any type argument*. So i.e.:

  ```
  List<List<?>> theAnyList = new ArrayList<List<?>>();

  // we can do this
  theAnyList.add( new ArrayList<String>() );
  theAnyList.add( new LinkedList<Integer>() );

  List<?> typeInfoLost = theAnyList.get(0);
  // but we are prevented from doing this
  typeInfoLost.add( new Integer(1) );
  ```

  We can put any `List` in `theAnyList`, but by doing so we have lost knowledge of *their elements*.
- When we use `? extends`, the `List` holds *some specific subtype of List, but we don't know what it is anymore*. So i.e.:

  ```
  List<? extends List<Float>> theNotSureList =
      new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>();

  // we can still use its elements
  // because we know they store Float
  List<Float> aFloatList = theNotSureList.get(0);
  aFloatList.add( new Float(1.0f) );

  // but we are prevented from doing this
  theNotSureList.add( new LinkedList<Float>() );
  ```

  It's no longer safe to add anything to the `theNotSureList`, because we don't know the actual type of its elements. (*Was* it originally a `List<LinkedList<Float>>`? Or a `List<Vector<Float>>`? We don't know.)
- We can put these together and have a `List<? extends List<?>>`. We don't know what type of `List` it has in it anymore, and we don't know the element type of *those* `List`s either. So i.e.:

  ```
  List<? extends List<?>> theReallyNotSureList;

  // these are fine
  theReallyNotSureList = theAnyList;
  theReallyNotSureList = theNotSureList;

  // but we are prevented from doing this
  theReallyNotSureList.add( new Vector<Float>() );
  // as well as this
  theReallyNotSureList.get(0).add( "a String" );
  ```

  We've lost information *both* about `theReallyNotSureList`, *as well as* the element type of the `List`s inside it.

  (But you may note that we can *assign* any kind of *List holding Lists* to it...)

So to break it down:

```
//   ┌ applies to the "outer" List
//   ▼
List<? extends List<?>>
//                  ▲
//                  └ applies to the "inner" List
```

The `Map` works the same way, it just has more type parameters:

```
//  ┌ Map K argument
//  │  ┌ Map V argument
//  ▼  ▼
Map<?, ? extends List<?>>
//                    ▲
//                    └ List E argument
```

#### Why `? extends` is necessary

You may know that ["concrete"](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ101) generic types have *invariance*, that is, [`List<Dog>` is not a subtype of `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p) even if `class Dog extends Animal`. Instead, the wildcard is how we have *covariance*, that is, `List<Dog>` *is* a subtype of `List<? extends Animal>`.

```
// Dog is a subtype of Animal
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}

// List<Dog> is a subtype of List<? extends Animal>
List<? extends Animal> a = new ArrayList<Dog>();

// all parameterized Lists are subtypes of List<?>
List<?> b = a;
```

So applying these ideas to a nested `List`:

- `List<String>` is a subtype of `List<?>` but `List<List<String>>` is *not* a subtype of `List<List<?>>`. As shown before, this prevents us from compromising type safety by adding wrong elements to the `List`.
- `List<List<String>>` *is* a subtype of `List<? extends List<?>>`, because the bounded wildcard allows covariance. That is, `? extends` allows the fact that `List<String>` is a subtype of `List<?>` to be considered.
- `List<? extends List<?>>` is in fact a shared supertype:

  ```
       List<? extends List<?>>
            ╱          ╲
  List<List<?>>    List<List<String>>
  ```

#### In review

1. `Map<Integer, List<String>>` accepts *only* `List<String>` as a value.
2. `Map<?, List<?>>` accepts *any* `List` as a value.
3. `Map<Integer, List<String>>` and `Map<?, List<?>>` are distinct types which have separate semantics.
4. One cannot be converted to the other, to prevent us from doing modifications in an unsafe way.
5. `Map<?, ? extends List<?>>` is a shared supertype which imposes safe restrictions:

   ```
           Map<?, ? extends List<?>>
                ╱          ╲
   Map<?, List<?>>     Map<Integer, List<String>>
   ```

---

#### How the generic method works

By using a type parameter on the method, we can assert that `List` has some concrete type.

```
static <E> void test(Map<?, List<E>> m) {}
```

This particular declaration requires that *all* `List`s in the `Map` have the same element type. We don't know what that type actually *is*, but we can use it in an abstract manner. This allows us to perform "blind" operations.

For example, this kind of declaration might be useful for some kind of accumulation:

```
static <E> List<E> test(Map<?, List<E>> m) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();

    for(List<E> value : m.values()) {
        result.addAll(value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

We can't call `put` on `m` because we don't know what its *key type* is anymore. However, we can manipulate its *values* because we understand they are all `List` with the same *element type*.

#### Just for kicks

Another option which the question does not discuss is to have both a bounded wildcard and a generic type for the `List`:

```
static <E> void test(Map<?, ? extends List<E>> m) {}
```

We would be able to call it with something like a `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>`. This is the most permissive declaration, if we only cared about the type of `E`.

We can also use bounds to nest type parameters:

```
static <K, E, L extends List<E>> void(Map<K, L> m) {
    for(K key : m.keySet()) {
        L list = m.get(key);
        for(E element : list) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is both permissive about what we can pass to it, as well as permissive about how we can manipulate `m` and everything in it.

---

#### See also

- [*"Java Generics: What is PECS?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2891664) for the difference between `? extends` and `? super`.
- [*JLS 4.10.2. Subtyping among Class and Interface Types*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) and [*JLS 4.5.1. Type Arguments of Parameterized Types*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) for entry points to the technical details of this answer.

Comment: I got that `List<List<?>>` is not the same as `List<? extends List<?>>`, that's clear for me. My question is more about why in my case I cannot use the former, when I can use the latter or even `List<List<E>>`.
Edit: "For the method that is generic, the one taking a Map<?, List<E>> that's a little different but basically similar." sorry?

Comment: Louis, the `? extends` applies to the `V` of the Map. Your Map has parameterized List as `V`. It means it can only store `List<String>` in it. A Map that takes `List<?>` takes any kind of List.

Comment: Okay, got it.

That's actually kinda logical.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Thank you for such a good explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the subclassing rules for generics are slightly different from what you may expect. In particular if you have:

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
```

then

`List<B>` is not a subclass of `List<A>`

It's explained in details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) and the usage of the wildcard (the "?" character) is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html).