# Java generic field

Tags: java, generics, casting

I don't see my mistake and don't understand why it doesn't work. I have following class:

```
public class Generic<K extends Comparable<K>> implements Comparable<Generic<K>> {
    // code

    public static List<Generic<String>> factory1(){...}
    public static List<Generic<Integer>> factory2(){...}

    private K mKey;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(NoteGroup<K> another) {
        return mKey.compareTo(another.mKey);
    }
}
```

In another class I don't care about the generic type and would like to use a wildcard like:

```
public class Anothter {
    private List<Generic<? extends Comparable>> mList;

    private void method1() {
        mList = Generic.factory1();
    }

    private void method2() {
        mList = Generic.factory2();
    }
}
```

But this does not work. The error message is, that a type extending Comparable is expected and not a String / Integer.

Can I solve my issue? Why can't I compile code snippet the above?

**Edit:** The error is in *method1()* and *method2()*. I cannot assign the result of the factory methods to the field *mList*. The types are incompatible.

Comment: What is Generic class? What is exactly error line?

Comment: *The error is in method1() and method2(). I cannot assign the result of the factory methods to the field mList. The types are incompatible.* and they will be. You cannot use `Foo<? extends Bar> bar` and just initialize it as you want. For example, think on `List<? extends Comparable> comparables = new ArrayList<Integer>();` but since the list supports any `Comparable` then you can add `String` or any other element that is a `Comparable` there, which the compiler cannot allow for *safety*.

Comment: `mList` contains any type of `Comparable`, which would allow any instance of any subclass of `Comparable` to be added to `mList`.

Comment: @SME_Dev that's not a proper solution.

Comment: @SME_Dev please read here: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1065197)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That doesn't work either. The generic types are still incompatible.

Comment: The whole problem is using `Foo<? extends Whatever> bar = ...` that's just plain wrong and you cannot use it, the compiler just don't understand what `Foo<? extends Whatever` is. Please read the accepted answer in the link I've provided. In short, you should not declare a variable using that approach.

Comment: Compiler does not understand that casting but it does not means we can't cast it at Runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java nested generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806202/java-nested-generic-type)

Comment: The declaration you are looking for is `List<? extends Generic<?>> mList;` but note a wildcard will not allow you to make comparisons easily.

Answer (score 1):

As said in one of the comments - To make your code work you need to change following declaration in class **Another**

```
private List<Generic<? extends Comparable>> mList;
```

to :

```
List<? extends Generic<?>> mList;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void method2() {
    mList = (List) Generic.factory2();
}
```