# List of a list of generic type in Java possible?

Tags: java, list, generics, generic-list

I have the following generic type:

```
public class Library<T> {}
```

I need to put each generic type into a list - for example:

```
ArrayList<Library<Photo>> listPhotoLibrary
    = new ArrayList<Library<Photo>>();
ArrayList<Library<Video>> listVideoLibrary
    = new ArrayList<Library<Video>>();
```

I then need to put these list into a generic list. First I tried this:

```
ArrayList<Library<?>> listTopLibrary = new ArrayList<Library<?>>();
```

The above code allowed me to add all libraries into a flat list. However, this is not what I want. What I want is to have the list of typed libraries within another list. For example, index 0 is a list of Video libraries, index 1 is a list of Photo libraries and so on. I tried the below to accomplish this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Library<?>>> listTopLibrary
    = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Library<?>>>();
```

This is not working. When I tried to add to the list, it is telling me:

```
The method add(ArrayList<Library<?>>) in the type ArrayList<ArrayList<Library<?>>>
is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Library<Photo>>)
```

Any idea why the compiler is complaining? And if there is a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a compilation error because `ArrayList<Library<?>>` is not a supertype of `ArrayList<Library<Photo>`. You can declare the array like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Library<?>>> listTopLibrary = new ArrayList<>();
```

A thorough explanation why can be found at [Java nested generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806202/java-nested-generic-type)

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer, and thank you for the link to the other, it was pretty hard to search for the right keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can Fix this by using

```
List<ArrayList<? extends Library<?>>> listTopLibrary = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Library<?>>` is not a supertype of `ArrayList<Library<Photo>>`

You have to declare `listTopLibrary` as

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends Library<?>>> listTopLibrary
```