# How to write a class with a nested template parameter?

Tags: java, templates, generics

I would like to know how to write a class in Java that has a nested template parameter. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22806202/4714742) describes nested, template parameters, but assumes that wildcards will be used. I would like to name all the types involved, so I don't want to use wildcards. Note that I understand that the wildcards are used for covariance. I am perfectly fine with my templated type being invariant as long as I know the types it's made out of. Below is an example of code that compiles, but doesn't give me all the information I want.

```
public class Parent<B> {

    public B b;

    public Parent(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public class Child<B> extends Parent<B> {

    public Child(B b) {
        super(b);
    }
}

public class Foo<ParentType extends Parent, B> {
    public ParentType parent;
    public B otherItem;

    public Foo(ParentType parent, B otherItem) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.otherItem = otherItem;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent<String> stringParent = new Parent<>("hello");
        Child<Integer> intChild = new Child<>(5);

        Foo<Parent, String> foo = new Foo<>(stringParent, "bonjour");
        Foo<Child, Integer> childFoo = new Foo<>(intChild, 42);

        Object b = foo.parent.b;
        System.out.println(b + ", " + b.getClass());
    }
}
```

I am forced to declare the type of `foo.parent.b` as an `Object`, even though I know it is a `String` (and the program knows it too: the output is `hello, class java.lang.String`). I would like to write the code more like this:

```
public class Foo<ParentType extends Parent, B> {
    public ParentType<B> parent;
//         ^ (5:12)
    public B otherItem;

    public Foo(ParentType<B> parent, B otherItem) {
//                     ^ same error here
        this.parent = parent;
        this.otherItem = otherItem;
    }
}
```

or something along those lines, explicitly forcing `parent`'s type to be linked to `B`, but IntelliJ complains `Type 'ParentType' does not have type parameters` and the compiler gives the error:

```
Error:(5, 12) java: unexpected type
  required: class
  found:    type parameter ParentType
```

The locations where the error occurs are marked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you didn't specify the type parameter of `Parent` here:

> ```
> Foo<Parent, String> foo = new Foo<>(stringParent, "bonjour");
> Foo<Child, Integer> childFoo = new Foo<>(intChildBar, 42);
>
> Object b = foo.parent.b;
> ```

Instead of `Foo<Parent, String>`, if you specify the type parameter of `Parent`, that is `Foo<Parent<String>, String>`, then you can get the correct type of `b`:

```
Foo<Parent<String>, String> foo = new Foo<>(stringParent, "bonjour");
Foo<Child, Integer> childFoo = new Foo<>(intChildBar, 42);

String b = foo.parent.b;
```

Comment: @JonMcClung if you read janos answer, it pretty much tells you the next answer, you know how he mentions to change the Parent to Parent<String>... are things clicking?

Comment: @Snickers3192 sorry, things aren't exactly clicking. I've tried just adding `<B>` to various parts of the class, but that only results in errors. My follow-up question is here if you'd like to provide more insight: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41217172/4714742

Comment: You need to add type parameters to Parent at the start of your Foo declaration. By the way your child class is redundant. You should think really carefully about how to use inheritance in your design of a class hierarchy. Helpful tip: if you don't add any methods to an inherited class, you probably don't need inheritance.