# Why is this HashMap declaration using generics wrong?

Tags: java, generics, serialization, arraylist, hashmap

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<? extends Serializable>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList>>();
```

This does not compile. To the best of my knowledge on Java Generics, it should. 
And this:

```
ArrayList<? extends Serializable> c = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

successfully compiles.

Can anyone say why the above wouldn't compile?

Comment: Perhaps `ArrayList<String>` doesn't extend `Serializable`?

Comment: Strongly related: [Java nested generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806202/java-nested-generic-type)

Comment: The fact that `A` extends (or implements) `B` doesn't imply that `HashMap<K,A>` extends `HashMap<K,B>`.  After all, a `HashMap<K,B>` is something that you can put a `B` in, but a `HashMap<K,A>` isn't.  Equivalent questions have been asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think that it should? A `HashMap<String, Apple>` is never assignable from a `HashMap<String, Orange>` for any possible unequal `Apple` and `Orange`, as long as both `Apple` and `Orange` are not wildcard-types.

And `ArrayList<? extends Serializable>` is not the same thing as `ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>`.

What you probably meant:

```
HashMap<String, ? extends ArrayList<? extends Serializable>> map = 
  new HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>>();
```

Now it compiles, because indeed:

```
? extends Serializable // can be assigned from
          ArrayList<?>
```

and

```
? extends ArrayList<? extends Serializable> // can be assigned from
          ArrayList<          ArrayList<?>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and it indeed works now.