# Passing a parameterized Map value to a wildcard signature parameter

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to use a wildcard type in a method signature and pass different parameterized types. It works fine if it's only a *GenericItemWrapper*, but it fails if that GenericItemWrapper is a type parameter itself. Here's what eclipse complains about:

```
The method DoStuff(Map<String, Test.GenericItemWrapper<?>>) in the type Test 
is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String, Test.GenericItemWrapper<String>>)
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Test
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Map<String, GenericItemWrapper<Long>> longWrapper = null;
    Map<String, GenericItemWrapper<String>> stringWrapper = null;

    Test t = new Test();
    t.DoStuff(longWrapper); // error here
    t.DoStuff(stringWrapper); // error here
  }

  public void DoStuff(Map<String, GenericItemWrapper<?>> aParam)
  {
    ;
  }

  public static class GenericItemWrapper<ItemType>
  {
    private ItemType mItem;

    public GenericItemWrapper(ItemType aItem)
    {
      mItem = aItem;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does not complain about:

```
public <T> void DoStuff(Map<String, GenericItemWrapper<T>> aParam) {
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`public void DoStuff(Map<String, ? extends GenericItemWrapper<?>> aParam) {}`

you can refer to this answer for more investigation about generics: [Java nested generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806202/java-nested-generic-type)

Basically the first `?` refers to the fact that you are creating a generic like `Map<String, ?>` and so you can put int the map any kind of Object.

The second `?`, the one inside the `GenericItemWrapper<?>` simply generalizes the item as you probably know.

So writing `Map<String, ? extends GenericItemWrapper<?>>` means that you are generalizing the Map value (using the first `?`) and that the type of generic object that you want to put inside the map has to be a generalized type too (aka `extends GenericItemWrapper<?>`)

Comment: Well.. it did come first.