# When a function returns a reference type which contains a generic, why do the rules for generics seem to change?

Tags: java, function, generics, return

I know that when making an initialization, the generic part must be identical. For example, this works:

```
List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
```

but this doesn't:

```
List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Keeping this concept in mind, I'm having trouble understanding why this function works:

```
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] num) {
    ...
    List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<>(); 
    ...
                    res.add(Arrays.asList(num[i], num[lo], num[hi]));
    ...
    return res;
}
```

It looks like threeSum returns a `LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>`; however, 
the reference type specified by the function is `List<List<Integer>>`.

My question is, why does Java not allow:

`List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`

But, does allow us to return `LinkedList<ArrayList<Integer>>()` when the specified reference type is `List<List<Integer>>`?

Comment: `res` is a reference of type `List<List<Integer>>`, so I don't understand your confusion. Are you worried that it's referencing an object of type `LinkedList`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22806587/1079354

Comment: `List` is a super type of `LinkedList`, so `List<X> res = new LinkedList<X>();` is valid, where `X` is `List<Integer>` in your first example. --- However, as the duplicate link explains, generic type arguments don't inherit, so `LinkedList<Animal> res = new LinkedList<Dog>()` is not valid, even though `Animal` aka `List<Integer>` is a super type of `Dog` aka `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the help. I do understand why `LinkedList<Animal> res = new LinkedList<Dog>()` is not valid, and I also read through the nested generic type post, but am still confused. I edited my question to make my confusion a little more clear.

Comment: @ayesup because `LinkedList<Animal>` might suggest you can add an `Animal`, maybe even a `Cat`. using bounded type parameters like `LinkedList<? extends Animal>`  more closely matches what you're looking for

Comment: @ayesup for what it's worth, the specification of `Arrays.<T>asList` does not state it necessarily returns an `ArrayList<T>` (and, in fact, it does not in standard JDK implementations). its return type is `List<T>`, which is consistent with the type parameter `List<T>` of the declared variable type (`List<List<T>>`)

Comment: Gotcha, I thought that List was an interface however, so it seems strange that we managed to directly instantiate a List somehow?