# Incompatible types when using nested upper-bounded wildcards

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, bounded-wildcard

I'm working on a [functional programming library](https://github.com/Zoybean/Functional) for Java, and I've hit a frustrating issue. I've got the following functions in my `Option<V>` class:

```
/**
 * Returns an Option containing the provided value.
 */
public static <V> Option<V> some(V value)
{...}

/**
 * Returns an Option that contains nothing.
 */
public static <V> Option<V> none()
{...}

/**
 * Decide control flow based on whether this is Some or None,
 * returning the result of the chosen operation.
 *
 * @param some the operation to perform on the contained value if there is one
 * @param none the operation to perform if there is no contained value
 * @return the result of the matched operation
 */
public <T> T matchThen(Function<? super V, ? extends T> some, Supplier<? extends T> none)
{...}
```

I'm currently implementing a method, `orElse`, that uses the methods above, and is implemented like so:

```
/**
 * Returns this if it is a Some, otherwise computes an Option from the given Supplier.
 * @param supp the supplier to compute the other Option
 * @return the first present value or None
 */
public Option<V> orElse(Supplier<? extends Option<? extends V>> supp)
{
    return matchThen(
            Option::some, // if there is a value, wrap it back up and return it
            supp::get     // if there isn't a value, get one from the supplier
    );
}
```

IDEA reports an error with the use of `Option::some` in `orElse`:

> Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert `Option<V>` to `? extends Option<? extends V>`

[My understanding of wildcard captures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) was that `Option<? extends V>` accepts any object of type `Option<T>` where `<T extends V>`, which would mean that an `Option<V>` is definitely an `Option<? extends V>`. Likewise, [I'd expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22806587/6112457) that a `? extends Option<? extends V>` type parameter would accept the same thing (an `Option<T>` as above or an `Option<V>`).

So, I have two questions:

1. Why is this error occurring? I've come to expect this to be *the case* where `? extends Type<? extends V>` works. Is my expectation being misapplied in this case? I can see how I could be misreading the error, as there's a few types involved, and I'll admit I'm not certain my above analysis is correct.
2. Is there a fix to the method signatures that doesn't sacrifice flexibility, or does so minimally? I'd love for users of this library to not have to worry about actually-compatible values and functions raising type errors because of my API.

### Note

I'm not asking for an implementation of `orElse` that avoids this type error; I have a tool for that already, and I don't care too much if my implementation uses minor workarounds. My main concern is that users of this library may face this type of issue when implementing their own solutions, so I want to make these methods as flexible type-wise as I can, which is why I have all these wildcards in the first place.

Comment: To the point as why the error is occurring 

     ```Function<? super V, ? extends T>```


means provided a value `V` you tend to return a something that extends `T`, that is what your `some` method doesn't do. It returns back the same type wrapped as an Option, i.e. `Option<V>`.

Comment: Here `T` is `Option<V>`

Answer (score 2):

Aah, nested wildcards.

Don't behave as you expect. Quick search gives [Multiple wildcards on a generic methods makes Java compiler (and me!) very confused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3546745/4725) as a candidate for canonical answer.

Effectively you are trying to get the type returned by `supp.get()` (`Option<? extends V>`) to be returned by `orElse` (`Option<V>`), which is not happening.

Presumably the interface for `Option` only uses `V` in a producer role, but there's no way of expressing that in Java.

An easy fix would be to make the return type `Option<? extends V>`.

You can retain the nicer interface by replacing the second argument of `matchThen` with a lambda function that unwraps the `Supplier` and the `Option<? extends V>` to a straight `V` reference, then rewraps as an `Option<V>`.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph there on un/rewrapping the Option, I've got a method (the workaround I mentioned), `static <V> Option<V> cast(Option<? extends V>)` for that exact purpose (handling covariance), but I'd rather not need to expose it as part of the API