# the difference between ? and letter on java generic

Tags: java, generics

I hava a list:

```java
List<Map<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and a method:

```java
public  void doSth(List<Map<String, ?>> list) {
}
```

calling it like this:

```java
doSth(list);
```

shows this error:

```
incompatible types: java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>>
```

However, this works:

```java
public <V>  void doSth(List<Map<String, V>> list) {
}
```

What's the difference butween `?` and `V`?

Comment: Check the [Java tutorials on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). Specifically the sections "Generic Types" and "Wildcards".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806202/java-nested-generic-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java treats type parameters that are embedded in within other type parameters differently from just plain old type parameters.  Specifically, because Java's generics are invariant, any type parameters embedded must either match exactly or you may have to throw in a `? extends` to satisfy the compiler's compile-time type safety requirement.

When the method expects a `List<Map<String, ?>>`, it's a list of maps that map strings to some specific yet unknown type, which may not be `Integer`.  The map may use any object type.

When you declare `V`, the compiler resolves `V` to `Integer` so that an exact match to the method is made.

You can also do one of the following: Use a wildcard in the declaration of `list`:

```
List<Map<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

or insert a `? extends` so the method can expect a subtype and not necessarily the exact match with regard to generics:

```
public static void doSth(List<? extends Map<String, ?>> list) {
}
```

or you can just match `Integer` for `Integer`:

```
public static void doSth(List<Map<String, Integer>> list) {
}
```