# Why does Java complain about use of generics in map but not list?

Tags: java, generics

I need to generically process a map containing a list, but can't get by the compiler warning.  It doesn't make sense why I can generically process the list, but not the map.

From the below code, why does the compiler allow the 'processList' method call, but not the call to 'processMap'?

It doesn't seem to matter what Java version (I've tried up to 19).   I can go to total base Java code (< 1.5) without generics, but, this simply makes no sense to me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C extends A { }

/**
 * <p>Why does the compiler complain about the calls to processMap?</p>
 */
public class GenericsMystery {
    public GenericsMystery() {
        ArrayList<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<C> cList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        processList(bList);
        processList(cList);
        
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<B>> bMap = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<C>> cMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        processMap(bMap);
        processMap(cMap);
    }
    
    public void processList(ArrayList<? extends A> list) {
    }
    
    public void processMap(HashMap<String, ArrayList<? extends A>> map) {
    }
}
```

Comment: HINT: `HashMap<String, ArrayList<? extends A>> bMap = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: You should use the interface *List* instead of the concrete class *ArrayList* in parameter.

Comment: Elliot:   I could have sworn that somewhere along the way of getting around it, I had tried that.... .but evidently not exactly that.   Thanks.   I still don't understand "why" Java requires it.

Comment: Jens:  Be that as it may, would that have solved the problem?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `? extends`  in front of the value type for `processMap` seems  to eliminate the compile warning.  I believe the real problem is you are changing the entire type of the parameter, to be something that is *extending* the original Array.  You can't change the *inside* of the map without actually changing the map type itself.

**Edit** In other words, try `public void processMap(HashMap<String, ? extends ArrayList<? extends A>> map)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I would have *never* come up with that.  For the life of me I cannot imagine why this is required. (more of a question than a statement).

Comment: FWIW, I come from a c++ background where templates are much more literal, so the way Java generics works for me was always a little bit of a "try some things and see what it likes", and then I try to rationalize why after I get it working.  Over time, it becomes more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, generics are **invariant**. A simpler version of your example can be demonstrated like so:

```java
List<C> cList = new ArrayList<>();
List<A> aList = cList; // fails to compile
```

The type `List<A>` declares that the generic type must **exactly** match `C`, so you cannot assign a `List<C>` to it (although `C` extends `A`).

You can make it **covariant** with `extends` and a wildcard or generic type parameter (for a method). `? extends A` allows the type to be either `A` or a subtype of `A`.

```java
List<? extends A> aList = cList;
```

Now, applying the same logic:

```java
HashMap<String, ArrayList<? extends A>> map
```

This declares that the type accepts exactly a `Map` whose key is of type `String` and value is of type `ArrayList<? extends A>`. But you are passing in a `Map` whose value is of type `ArrayList<C>`. This does not exactly match the type parameter `ArrayList<? extends A>` (which is invariant although the type parameter to `ArrayList` has `extends`).

Comment: Understood.  But way isn't is complaining about 'processList'?  In my mind, it is somewhat the same.

Comment: @JMorgan You're passing `ArrayList<C>` to `ArrayList<? extends A>` and `C` does match `? extends A` (the first level type parameter). The covariance achieved with `extends` is not recursive.